# Speccing out new features

Tags: project-planning, specifications

I am curious as to how other development teams spec out new features. The team I have just moved up to lead has no real specification process. I have just implemented a proper development process with CI, auto deployment and logging all bugs using Trac and I am now moving on to deal with changes.

I have a list of about 20 changes to our product to have done over the next 2 months. Normally I would just spec out each change going into detail of what should be done but I am curious as to how other teams handle this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we had a successful approach in my last job as we delivered the project on time and with only a couple of issues found in production. However, there were only 3 people working on the product, so I'm not entirely sure how it would scale to larger teams.

We wrote specs upfront for the whole product but without going into too much detail and with an emphasis on the UI. This was a means for us to get a feel for what had to be done and for the scope of the project.

When we started implementing things, we had to work everything out in a lot more detail (and inevitably had to do some things differently from the spec). To that end, we got together and worked out the best approach to implementing each feature (sometimes with prototypes). We didn't update the original spec but we did make notes after the meetings as it's very easy to forget the details afterwards.

So in summary, my approach is to treat specs as an exploratory tool and to work out finer details during implementation. Depending on the project, it may also be a good idea to keep the original spec up to date as the application evolves (which we didn't need to do this time).

Comment: It was billable. The people you're talking about aren't "architects" but rather business analysts I think. However, this isn't a discussion for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Good question but its can be subjective. I guess it depends on the strategy of the product, if its to be deployed to multiple clients in the same way or to a single client on a bespoke project, the impact, dependency these changes have on the system and each other and the priority these changes need to be made.
I would look at the priority and the dependency, that will naturally start grouping things?